# RSpec - Request for not existing record has response with status 200

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

After adding decent_exposure the following spec is failed:

```
it "redirects to root_path if product cannot be found" do
  product = create :product
  get :show, {id: 2}

  expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path)
end
```

I use CanCanCan and add the following code to ApplicationController, so it rescues when the record couldn't be found and redirects to root path:

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do
  redirect_to root_path, alert: controller_name.singularize.capitalize << " cannot be found"
end
```

And it do works, it redirects if a record doesn't exist and I see 'Completed 302 Found' message in console. But spec fails with the message 'Expected response to be a redirect, but was <200>'. Seems to be it's due to 'Rendered products/show.html.haml within layouts/application' before 'Redirected to http://localhost:3000/' which appears after adding decent_exposure.

In controller I have only:

```
expose(:product, attributes: :product_params)
expose(:products) { Product.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5) }
```

without Show action.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Added Show action:

```
def show
  return unless product
end
```

Now it works correctly.